# Should I cast size_t to int or keep the interface to size_t

Tags: c++

Lets say you get a vector of ints.  Doing all the operations on them, such as iterating over them, you use size_t.  Is it best to make your interface return the receiving type, or return size_t?

In other words, say I want to return a list of ints, but size_t is way more convenient, is it best to cast all of them, or just let the caller deal with it?

In other (code) words,

```
unordered_map<size_t, size_t> indexFun(vector<int> sumNumbers) {
    unordered_map<size_t, size_t> someThings;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sumNumbers.size(); ++i) {

        // do something with indices
        size_t iMutated = i - 5;
        someThings[i] = iMutated;
    }

    return someThings;
}
```

Comment: What version of Javascript is this?

Comment: Your example won't compile. You are returning `unordered_map<size_t, size_t>` from a function declared to return `vector<size_t>`

Comment: Thanks for the catch, i typed it in directly instead of double checking the output, like a noob.

Comment: `i - 5` on an unsigned variable looks suspicious. Are you sure you want a wraparound here? It is also somewhat surprising that the return value of `indexFun` doesn't depend on any values in `sumNumbers`, only its size. Why does the type of elements of `sumNumbers` matter, if you don't ever look at those elements?

Comment: No, its returning indices.  Therefore, the natural unit is size_t and not int, but the calling interface uses int so it feels funny.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling interface"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: I heard rust had a good feature for this

Comment: What I mean by the calling interface is that the interface accepts vector<int> then returns ...<size_t..> which does not seem ideal.

Comment: Interfaces should be easy to use, hard to misuse. If the return is an index, or indices, then it should be `size_t` so it's harder for the caller to make mistakes.

Comment: "Best" depends on what the interface is and how it should be used. It should not depend on how the data is generated. But that borders dangerously close to being a matter of opinion...

Comment: @JaMiT hey thanks man.  That is a useful answer.  I will go forth and prosper.

Comment: Your question is not clear.